# Converting CPL/EPL into PDF

Tags: pdf, printing, epl

I am making an API call to a third party to receive back tickets for an event. The only formats that the tickets can be sent back from the API are:

> `text/vnd.citizen-clp` - for use with Citizen Thermal Printers
>
> `text/vnd.eltron-epl` - intended for use with Electron Printer (or certain printer models that support EPL emulation)

My challenge is that users on my site need to be given their tickets so they can print them. These users won't have Citizen or Electron Printers. I need to convert either the `CPL` or `EPL` into `PDF` format so my customers can print their tickets.

Other suppliers in the past have sent me tickets in ZPL format and I am using the API from http://labelary.com/ to convert `ZPL` to `PDF` -- this works perfectly. Unfortunately Labelary only support `ZPL` and not `CPL` or `EPL`.

My backend code is written in PHP.

So, is there any tool I can install onto my server to convert `CPL`/`EPL` to `PDF`? Or are there any tools online (free or commercial) where I can send my `CPL`/`EPL` and receive back a `PDF`?

Comment: Unfortunately, questions asking for recommendation of tools are OT here on SO though  there should be some place where this could legally be discussed...?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I would prefer not to use a tool but instead have something I can install onto my server so I can run a command to do the conversion. A third party tool is my last resort!!

Comment: Hm, maybe I'm nitpicking, but "something I can install onto my server so I can run a command to do the conversion" does sound like a "tool" to me? Not meant to be offensive.

Comment: Ha, oops, sorry. I misread your message. I thought your original comment was about asking for recommendations about 3rd party systems that I could make an API request to to perform the conversion.

Comment: No problem - good luck!

Comment: Did you get an answer to this @Chris? I'm looking for a similar solution.